# android:export when migrating to Android 12 in Flutter AndroidManifest

Tags: android, flutter

I'm migrating my flutter app to Android 12 and I don't know where exactly I've to put the android:export lines in my AndroidManifest.
I've tries several options but always the console throws me an error about this.
This is my AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.atgapp.atgapp">
   <application
        android:label="atgapp"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icono"
        android:exported="true">
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
           android:resource="@mipmap/icon" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
       <service
           android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
           </intent-filter>
       </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just update your `Service` tag

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: I continue recieving an error: adb: failed to install C:\Users\alber\OneDrive\Escritorio\atgapp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl334403273.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #173): com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

Comment: just like what I said in my answer, you probably should update https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications in Github seems to have v13.0.0 available.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you open the app in Android Studio and go through your Manifest you should find warnings for exporting services/activities, fix those by adding the suggested.

After, you should create a API 31 emulator (with Android 12) and try running your app, you will probably receive an error caused by some library that is not updated, like the following:

> Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed:
> INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
>
> List of apks: [0]
> 'C:\Users\------\Desktop-----\=====\mobile\build\outputs\apk\debug\mobile-debug.apk'
> Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED:
> Failed parse during installPackageLI:
> /data/app/vmdl1980686865.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #294):
> com.instacart.library.truetime.BootCompletedBroadcastReceiver:
> Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value
> for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'

for the example above, the library TrueTime is outdated, updating it resolved the problem.